# Обязательно ли переопределять виртуальные методы класса в наследнике наследника, если нет как этого избежать?

Tags: c++

Есть класс

```
class Abstract {
 public:
  virtual void somemethod() = 0;
}
class ConcreteChild : public Abstract {
 public:
 void somemethod() { ..code.. };
}
class ConcreteGrandsone : ConcreteChild {
 public:
  void somemethode2();
}
```

Если в `ConcreteGrandsone` не переопределяю `somemethod` то класс получается абстрактным.

В классе `ConcreteGrandsone` метод `somemethod` должен вести себя так же как и в `ConcreteChild` его обязательно переопределять как `void somemethod() {ConcreteChild::somemethod();}`, или есть способ наследования конкретного поведения этого метода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Если в ConcreteGrandsone не переопределяю somemethod то класс получается абстрактным.

Нет, если это вопрос :)

Если вы это сделаете — не определите

```
void somemethod() { ..code.. };
```

в `ConcreteChild`, то да, этот класс будет абстрактным. Но наследник конкретного класса

```
class ConcreteGrandsone : ConcreteChild {
```

по этой причине абстрактным не будет. Убедитесь: https://ideone.com/4mvIl6